# Prevent floating DIVs from overlapping footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a page with a header, two columns and a footer. I don't want a scroll bar to appear for the page, but allow the columns to scroll if the data overflows.

Currently my best attempt is this:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="side-text">
      <p>Menu Items</p>
      <p>Menu Items</p>
      <p>Menu Items</p>
      <p>Menu Items</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-text">
      <p>...Snip...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>...snip...</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, .content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content > div {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.side-text {
    width: 15%;
}

.main-text {
    width: 85%;
}

footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but the content in the right div flows over the footer (and even past the end of the `<body>`).

JSFiddle of the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/gcd7d238/

Comment: Your footer is positioned absolutely, it's always going to be there flowing over your text.

Comment: Indeed. Is there any way to accomplish the same kind of positioning without using `position: absolute`? Put the header div at the top, the footer at the bottom, and have the two floating divs in the middle use up the remaining space? I suppose I could position everything in JS, but I was trying to do this in just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent it from going over the footer, all you need to do is change the content height:

```
.content > div {
    float: left;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gcd7d238/2/

**UPDATE:**

To make it more responsive you can use `display:table`:

```
body{
  display: table;
}
.content {
  display: table-row;
  height: 95%;
}
footer {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gcd7d238/3/

Comment: [**don't work in reduced viewports**](https://i.gyazo.com/7b4697491a14f4281a92f68327a5e9d9.png)