# Stop div from overlapping

Tags: html, css

Ok so first things first. I have searched about this topic and did manage to find this:

[Prevent floating DIVs from overlapping footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264292/prevent-floating-divs-from-overlapping-footer)

However this did not solve my issue. I have also attempted other forms of rewriting the css code I have set but the results would in turn mess up my body content.

My index.php code:

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">



<title>
Shadey Process


        </title>





<body>
<?php
include 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
?>

<div class="body">
This is the body.
Due to errors beyond my control everything I had worked so hard to do is gone.
</div>
<?php
include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
</body>


</html>
```

My main.css code:

```css
@font-face { 
        font-family: Kingdom; src: url('../addons/font/Kingdom.ttf'); 
} 
.header {
    padding: 20px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: green;
    font-family: Kingdom;
    font-size: 98px;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    
}
.body {

    color: red;
    margin-right: 34%;
}
.navlinks {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    length: 100%;
    background: black;
}
.footer {
  float: left;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}
```

My navigation.php code:

```html
<style>
.btn-group {
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: green;
}

.button {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
}

.btn-group .button:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}


.home {
    background-color: black; 
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
}
.home:hover {
    background-color:   #800000; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
.forum {
    background-color: black; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: green;
}
.forum:hover {
    background-color: #7CFC00; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
.alpha {
    background-color: black; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: blue;
}
.alpha:hover {
    background-color: #0000FF; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
.games {
    background-color: black; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    color: yellow;
}
.games:hover {
    background-color: #FFFF00; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
}
</style>





<div class="btn-group navlinks">

  <?php 
  if($_SESSION['user']==false)
    { 

      echo '
       <a href="index.php" class="button home">Home</a>
  <a href="forum.php" class="button forum">Forum</a>
  <a href="alpha.php" class="button alpha">Alpha</a>
  <a href="games.php" class="button games">Games</a> 
      <a href="includes/login/index.php" class="button home">Login</a>';
    }
  else{
      echo "<font color= 'red'>Glad to have you {$_SESSION["user"]}</font>";
      
      echo '
        <a href="index.php" class="button home">Home</a>
  <a href="forum.php" class="button forum">Forum</a>
  <a href="alpha.php" class="button alpha">Alpha</a>
  <a href="games.php" class="button games">Games</a>
      <a href="includes/logout/logout.php" class="button forum">Logout</a>';
    }
  ?>
  
  
  
  
  

</div>
```

My footer.php

```html
<div class="footer", "container-fluid" style="bottom:0; position:fixed;">
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;
background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-image:linear-gradient
(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%),
linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, white 25%, white 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%);" 
src="https://multicraft.mcprohosting.com/index.php?r=status/606439.png">
</div>
```

This is the rendered Html after using view source:

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">



<title>
Shadey Process


        </title>





<body>
<div class="header">
Shadey Process
</div><style>
.btn-group {
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: green;
}

.button {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
}

.btn-group .button:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}


.home {
    background-color: black; 
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
}
.home:hover {
    background-color:   #800000; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
.forum {
    background-color: black; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: green;
}
.forum:hover {
    background-color: #7CFC00; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
.alpha {
    background-color: black; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: blue;
}
.alpha:hover {
    background-color: #0000FF; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
}
.games {
    background-color: black; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    color: yellow;
}
.games:hover {
    background-color: #FFFF00; /* Green */
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
}
</style>





<div class="btn-group navlinks">

  
       <a href="index.php" class="button home">Home</a>
  <a href="forum.php" class="button forum">Forum</a>
  <a href="alpha.php" class="button alpha">Alpha</a>
  <a href="games.php" class="button games">Games</a> 
      <a href="includes/login/index.php" class="button home">Login</a>  
  
  
  
  

</div>
<div class="body">
This is the body.
Due to errors beyond my control everything I had worked so hard to do is gone.
</div>

<div class="footer", "container-fluid" style="bottom:0; position:fixed;">
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;
background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-image:linear-gradient
(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%),
linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, white 25%, white 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%);" 
src="https://multicraft.mcprohosting.com/index.php?r=status/606439.png">
</div></body>


</html>
```

Any help and/or criticism would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What divs are overlapping? You realize your header and footer aren't rendering here, right? And your footer is after `</body>` - it should come before that tag.

Comment: from the looks of your css, you probably need a clearfix https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: My apologies. I failed to add that I had tried adding 
**clear: both;** to the .footer div and the .navlinks div but the problem continued.

Comment: can you include the rendered HTML (not the PHP) then? And have you tried moving the footer above `</body>`?

Comment: I edited my question to include my index.php and my navigations.php. I also attempted moving the footer above the `</body>` and it did not help.

Comment: As @MichaelCoker asked previously, please include the HTML your browser gets (try right-clicking and selecting View Source) in your question. Note that Stack Snippets may not the way to go here, unless you provide that HTML; try clicking on the Run code snippet buttons in your question to see why.

Comment: It most likely is my navigation.php that is the issue. i took out the 100% from `.btn-group { height= 100%` and that reduced the div border i have set to just the area where the navigation buttons are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include your header file after `</body>` tag. include the `<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>` footer withing your `<body>` tags

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ?>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <title>
    Shadey Process
  </title>
  <body>
    <?php
      include 'includes/header.php';
      include 'includes/navigation.php';
      ?>
    <div class="body">
      This is the body.
      Due to errors beyond my control everything I had worked so hard to do is gone.
    </div>
    <?php
      include 'includes/footer.php';
      ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Updated** (after read Mike's comment)

if still doesn't work this.i think problem is in your `footer.php` please post your `footer.php` here or put this code line to your footers div

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="bottom:0; position:fixed;">
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: From [the OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548198/stop-div-from-overlapping#comment74149177_43548198): *I also attempted moving the footer above the </body> and it did not help.*

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i updated it :) i think problem is in his `footer.php`